# 04 chevy trailblazer tailight and control issues

Tags: trailblazer, brake-light, heater-control

I let someone drive my vehicle, someone that I probably shouldn't have. When I got the vehicle back, the heater control panel in the back seat was pulled out and broken. Also, all the wires underneath my driver seat had been pulled out. I didn't realize it but my tail lights are not working. The only lights that are working on my tail lights are the brake lights. Shouldn't the entire taillights be lit up? What should I do?

Comment: Make the person you lent it to pay for the repairs? (or have them arrested for criminal damage). Also learn never to lend a vehicle to anyone you don't trust 100% ;-)

Comment: I agree with @NickC. Make them pay for the repairs. Their damages; their repairs. If they don't want to pay for the repairs, take them to small claims court or maybe even sue them for it if it is too much for the smaller court. Don't be nice about it, that's for sure. It's your vehicle. You lent it to them with an expectation to receive it back in the same condition you lent it to them in.

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: While it doesn't help with your specific question, I also agree that you should talk to the police about the damages.*

My suspicion is that whoever was monkeying around with your wiring and electronics managed to cross several wires and blow some fuses.  I would start with the fuse box unless you're certain that some of the wiring is damaged.  If that's the problem, fuses are pretty cheap to replace (and at least you'd have functional tail lights).